# Slowing down Integral from linear to quadratic

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why does Mathematica get stuck if I compute this integral and not if I compute the same one with b rather than b^2?

```
N[Abs[b^2 - I + Sinh[2 I]]]
Integrate[%, {b, 0, 1}]

N[Abs[b - I + Sinh[2 I]]]
Integrate[%, {b, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: @FredSimons how do you understand if a closed form exist or not?

Comment: @FredSImons What do you mean, no closed form exists? The modulus in the first case is $\sqrt{b^4 + (\sin(2) -1)^2},$ which integrates (substitute ($\sqrt{1 - \sin 2}$ for $a$) to:

$$\frac{x \left(a+x^4\right)-\frac{2 i a \sqrt{\frac{a+x^4}{a}} F\left(\left.i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{i}{\sqrt{a}}}
   x\right)\right|-1\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{i}{\sqrt{a}}}}}{3 \sqrt{a+x^4}}.$$

Comment: @IgorRivin may I ask you why I still see imaginary units if I was looking for the absolute value?

Comment: What do you mean by "imaginary units"?

Comment: @IgorRivin that i term?

Comment: The elliptic F might be (in fact, is) real at this imaginary value).

Comment: Ugh, that's not the best-looking elliptic integral I've seen. I've been complaining for quite a while that *Mathematica* is not very good at returning "practical" elliptic integral results. I'll see what I can do later...

Comment: @J.M. Mankind will thank you.

Comment: @Igor. I wrote that very likely no closed from would exist, based on the fact that I could not see how to get rid of the function Abs with a non-real argument. You found a formula for the absolute value, so my feeling was very incorrect. Very nice to see your solution!

Comment: @FredSimons `Abs[]` is overloaded, and quite confusing...

Answer (score 4):

If `b` is real, use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
f[b_] = Abs[b^2 - I + Sinh[2 I]] // ComplexExpand

(*  Sqrt[b^4 + (-1 + Sin[2])^2]  *)

int[b_] = Integrate[f[b], b] // FullSimplify

(*  (1/(3 Sqrt[2]))((-2 + 2 I) EllipticF[
    ArcSin[((-1)^(1/4) b)/(-Cos[1] + Sin[1])], -1] (Cos[1] - Sin[1])^3 + 
  b Sqrt[3 + 2 b^4 - Cos[4] - 4 Sin[2]])  *)
```

Verifying,

```
D[int[b], b] == f[b] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

**EDIT:**

If you use an exact argument, say `2`, Mathematica will return an exact result, i.e., a mostly unevaluated expression

```
int[2]

(*  (1/(3 Sqrt[2]))((-2 + 2 I) EllipticF[
    ArcSin[(2 (-1)^(1/4))/(-Cos[1] + Sin[1])], -1] (Cos[1] - Sin[1])^3 + 
  2 Sqrt[35 - Cos[4] - 4 Sin[2]])  *)
```

If you provide a machine precision number you will get a machine precision result and for finite precision the imaginary parts may not cancel.

```
int[2.]

(*  2.69837 + 5.71865*10^-18 I  *)
```

You can use [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to eliminate components smaller than the specified tolerance, the default is `10^-10` but can be made smaller if desired.

```
int[2.] // Chop // InputForm

(*  2.6983748731394215  *)
```

You can get more precise results with more precise inputs

```
{int[2.`16], int[2.`20]}

(*  {2.69837487313942 + 0.*10^-15 I, 2.698374873139421773 + 0.*10^-19 I}  *)

% // Chop

(*  {2.69837487313942, 2.698374873139421773}  *)
```

Alternatively, if you know the result is real and any imaginary part is an artifact of loss of precision, you can use `Re` to eliminate the imaginary component.

**EDIT 2:**

```
int /@ {-9.4, 9.4}

(*  {-276.895 - 1.71559*10^-17 I, 276.895 + 1.71559*10^-17 I}  *)
```

Notwithstanding the imaginary artifacts, [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) ignores these and plots the function as real

```
Plot[int[b], {b, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

As seen in the `Plot`, `int` is an odd function

```
int[b] == -int[-b] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: if you then compute int[2], for instance, why don't I get directly a numerical value? I have to run N[int[2]]. Secondly, and that is really important to me: the value I obtain with N[int[2]] is 2.69837 + 5.71865*10^-18 I. For as small as the imaginary part is, however, why is there an imaginary part if asked for the integral of an Absolute value? Am I wrong in expecting a 0 imaginary part from the Abs[anything] in Mathematics?

Comment: @AndreaG - see EDIT

Comment: Here I have an important question: when you say "if I know that the result is real",in my case, why shouldn't the result be real? I mean, as I was computing the Abs value, why do I have to take care of machine precision? shouldnt mathematica know that there is no Imaginary unit after Abs?

Comment: @AndreaG - Mma knows that `Abs` has a real value. However, the resulting expr does not carry any info about its heritage and when evaluated for a specific argument it merely executes a sequence of operations that result in some loss of precision and the imaginary artifacts. Since you know that the expression is an output of `Abs` you can choose to use `Chop` or `Re` to eliminate these artifacts caused by loss of infinite numerical precision. Sometimes symbolic expressions can be manipulated into forms that are manifestly real and which do not generate any imaginary artifacts; not in this case.

Comment: do you suggest to use machine precision numbers in my expressions: for exemple the squares ^2. rather than ^2? Is it always better Sqrt[] or ^1/2? Or ^1/2. ? I am trying to understand also this. If imaginary is an artifact, can I trust, anyway, the real part result?

Comment: @AndreaG - No, leave the exact numbers in the function definitions. You can then control the precision through the inputs (exact or approximate reals) or by using `N[exact, prec]//Re` or `exact//N//Re`. Also, note from `x^(1/2) // FullForm` and `Sqrt[x] // FullForm` that either form of input produces the same internal representation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the OP is using `N[]`, but without it, the indefinite integral of the first form comes out to 
$$
\frac{\sqrt[4]{2} x \left(2 x^4+3-4 \sin (2)-\cos (4)\right)+4 (-1)^{3/4} \sqrt[4]{2}
   (\sin (1)-\cos (1))^5 \sqrt{\frac{x^4}{(\cos (1)-\sin (1))^4}+1} F\left(\left.\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{(1+i) x}{\sqrt{2} (\cos (1)-\sin (1))}\right)\right|-1\right)}{3\
   2^{3/4} \sqrt{2 x^4+3-4 \sin (2)-\cos (4)}},
$$
very quickly. Evaluating the antiderivative at $0$ and $1$ is also fast. However, the *definite* integral takes a long time (but does return eventually), so this is a bug in the definite integrator, but not a major one, since the answer appears to be correct:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{5-4 \sin (2)-\cos (4)}+(-2+2 i) (\cos (1)-\sin (1))^3 F\left(\left.\csc
   ^{-1}\left((-1)^{3/4} (\cos (1)-\sin (1))\right)\right|-1\right)}{3 \sqrt{2}},
$$
with a numerical value of $0.362986.$

Comment: Probably taking time to assess convergence and presence or lack of path singularities.